# Jira Server and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Jira Server with Jenkins. Most tutorials I found was about Jira Cloud and for Server I found this plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211376/jenkins-integration-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview. Unfortunately this plugin will be not supported in few months. I also tried to use this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira/ (jenkins version is 2.401.1) - I've created Personal Access Token, added credentials to jenkins, but after settings validation I'm getting error with log id: `Logging ID=67e73b7c-4989-418e-a480-e5101dcc5ad8` My `Jira URL` is: `https://jira.company.com/` and with credentials I tried to use password and PAT, but both options didn't work.

Could somebody tell me what I'm missing in configuration or what I'm doing wrong?